# My warn command is not working discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

(Replit.com) I tried to use the warn command but every time i try, there is a error: **TypeError: 'Command' object is not subscriptable**

```
with open('warns.json', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    try:
        report = json.load(f)
    except ValueError:
        report = {}
        report['users'] = []
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True, ban_members=True)
async def warn(ctx, user: discord.User, *reason: str):
  if not reason:
    await ctx.send("Please provide a reason")
    return
    author = ctx.author
    reason = ' '.join(reason)
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f'{author.name} warned {user.name} for')
  for current_user in report['users']:
    if current_user['name'] == user.name:
      current_user['reasons'].append(reason)
      break
  else:
      report['users'].append({
            'name': user.name,
            'reasons': [
                reason,
            ]
        })
  with open('warns.json', 'w+') as f:
    json.dump(report, f)
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

The error message I get is:

```
File "main.py", line 411, in warn 
    for current_user in report['users']: 
TypeError: 'Command' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Please avoid uploading code as an image.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that aside the `report` dictionary,  you also have a command called `report`,  so to fix this error, simply rename either the global variable or the command.
Also instead of saving the users by name, you should save them by their id (`current_user.id` instead of `current_user.name` ), because Nitro users can change their discriminator to avoid any warns.